# bash: removing many files of the same extension

Tags: bash, rm

I am dealing with the folder consisted of many log filles. I have to remove all of them using bash. My version using rm does not work:

```
rm "${results}"/*.log
```

that gives me:

```
./dolche_vita.sh: line 273: /usr/bin/rm: Argument list too long
```

Comment: BTW: You're not even asking a question but asking the right question is key to solving your problems! Please, as a new user here, read [ask] and take the [tour].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This means, there are so many `.log` files in that directory, that the argument list for the `rm` call gets too long. (The `*.log` gets expanded to `file1.log`, `file2.log`, `file3.log`, ... during the "real" `rm` call and there's a limit for the length of this argument line.)

A quick solution could be using `find`, like this:

```sh
find ${results}/ -type f -name '.log' -delete
```

Here, the `find` command will list all files (`-type f`) in your `${results}` dir, ending with `.log` (because of `-name '.log'`) and delete them because you issue `-delete` as last parameter.

Comment: Thanks! I guess it should be find folder -type f -name '*.log' -delete

Comment: Note to the OP: run `find` *without* `-delete` and check the output before you add the switch in.  It's too easy to construct `find` calls which pull in more than you thought they did (prob not relevant with an invocation this simply, but there's still the possibility of a typo).